# Missing software entry when using Win32_Product Class

Tags: c#, wmi, windows-7-x64, windows-server-2012-r2, domaincontroller

I have test environment with Windows Server 2012R2 running domain controller and client in this domain with Windows 7 SP1.

I use this code in order to get a list of installed software from client:

```
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\10.0.0.101\\root\\cimv2");
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product Where AssignmentType = 1");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject item in queryCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item["Name"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("PackageName: " + item["PackageName"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("PackageCode: " + item["PackageCode"].ToString());                
        }
```

My problem is that I get only a list of software that I installed on a client before I joined it to the domain. Anything is installed on the client after its connection to a domain, I do not see it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with the help of remote registry instead of WMI.